# Format date returned from visualisation API query

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-visualization

I am using the google visualisation API to query a spreadsheet that has dates in one column, the problem is that when I use the dates returned from the query to populate another spreadsheet, they are incorrectly formatted.

Thus far I have already tried the following

```
  var queryResult = sheetQuery(
      "Sheet1", 
      "A1:A", 
      "select A format A 'dd/mm/yyy'"
  );
  var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 2, 8, 1);
  range.clear();
  range.setValues(queryResult).setHorizontalAlignment("left");
```

please pay particular attention to my use of the format clause at the end of the query (4th parameter).

I have also tried to manually format the date cells as follows:

```
sheet.getRange(1, 2, 8, 1).setNumberFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
```

However, the dates simply do not format and stay formatted like this:
Date(2018,8,21,9,0,0)
Date(2018,8,21,9,15,4)
Date(2018,8,21,9,30,0)
Date(2018,8,21,9,45,0)
Date(2018,8,23,10,0,19)
Date(2018,8,24,10,15,0)
Date(2018,8,24,10,30,0)
Date(2018,8,24,10,45,43)

I have set up an example spreadsheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/160sp6T0dEvq_s5X6gGx_mH-9dj2fBf7co80On01JqWw/edit?usp=sharing

To reproduce the issue, find mainFunction script and run. here is a link to the script: https://script.google.com/d/1kRavDwa0HKSuFRk6UKram1j7UzcaSow7mwfWBolSZoHwARaVF6Ifh_iF/edit?usp=sharing

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure why someone downvoted, I put a lot of effort into ensuring there was enough information and a working example

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by looping over the date array, and for each date I modified the string the remove the date and brackets, split the string into an array and passed a few of the values from the array to a new date object:

```
for (var j = 0; j < queryResult.length; j++) {
  var previousDate = queryResult[j][2];
  var dateArray = previousDate.substring(previousDate.indexOf('(') + 1, previousDate.indexOf(')')).split(',');
  for (var k = 0; k < dateArray.length; k++) {
    dateArray[k] = parseInt(dateArray[k]);
  }
  queryResult[j][2] = new Date(dateArray[0], dateArray[1], dateArray[2], dateArray[3], dateArray[4], dateArray[5]);
}
```